# pass a list to js to display a chart

Tags: javascript, html, django

Hi I am new to Js and I have some issues to display my chart property.
I am trying to pass a list to the template, then grab by my js scrpit, and last pass that list to display chart.

I have this tag in my template:

```
<div style="display: none" id="listData" listmonth="{{ month_profit_list }}"></div>
```

Then pass to js file like this:

```
var ctx1 = $("#worldwide-sales").get(0).getContext("2d");
const div1 = document.getElementById('listData');
var listMonth = div1.getAttribute('listmonth');
console.log(listMonth)
var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
        datasets: [{
                label: "USA",
                data: listMonth,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .7)"
            },
           
        ]
        },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
});
```

My list is fine and the output in cosole is this = [129, -69, 226, 25, 151, 114, -79, 4, 49, 61, -76, 65]
but I got this chart:
[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `listMonth` is a string not a list, use `json_script` filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

Comment: Use **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** eg. **`data: JSON.parse(listMonth)`**

Answer (score -1):

That's odd. I reproduced your code inside the [w3schools chartjs tryit playground](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryai_chartjs_bars_colors_more), amending the original example like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Ago","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
var yValues = [129, -69, 226, 25, 151, 114, -79, 4, 49, 61, -76, 65];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      label: "USA",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 156, 255, .7)",
      data: yValues
    },]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and it worked well:
[image: w3schools version]

Unless I missed something, maybe it has to do with some external code/settings, say on the canvas or else (I don't know if some piece of CSS might interfere with the library)? Or possibly the `listMonth` variable displays well in the console but needs to be cleaned before passing it in?